# update app.config.xml in Perl

Tags: c#, xml, perl

I have a test.config file. Its a configuration file for c# program. which looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="key1" value="val1, val2, val3, val4"/>
        <add key="key2" value="val1, val2, val3, val4"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to write a PERL script which can retrieve the value for a given key and then change the value in the file.

I am new to Perl and There are several libraries for XML, for what I am trying to achive what would be the most elegant, efficient approach ??

Comment: The term "fancy logic" is highly subjective; what I consider fancy may be different from others. If you want to get a list of modules, [search `CPAN`](https://metacpan.org). If you want an example, many CPAN modules come with a Synopsis section in the documentation. If you want someone to code it for you, let me refer you to the site's [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: by fancy I meant something which is NOT elegant, and inEfficient. I dont want some to code it for me, I simply want head start,where I can focus my study !!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at what [Task::Kensho:XML](https://metacpan.org/module/Task%3a%3aKensho#XML-Development%3a-Task%3a%3aKensho%3a%3aXML) says for this.  Quoting the [description](https://metacpan.org/module/Task%3a%3aKensho#DESCRIPTION-):

> Task::Kensho is a first cut at building a list of recommended modules
>   for Enlightened Perl development. CPAN is wonderful, but there are too
>   many wheels and you have to pick and choose amongst the various
>   competing technologies.

For instance [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) would probably be a good starting point.